# Daily balance change in a table with irregular load dates and missing balances

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in a MSSQL database where a set of balances is loaded irregularly (currently all work days but some past days may be missing). Only items with non-zero balances are loaded (so if an account has a zero balance, it will be missing from the daily load due to the logic of the originating system).

I am trying to figure out a way to create a view that would calculate daily increase/decrease of the balance of each of the accounts that had balance on either of two consecutive load days.
Moreover, for reporting purposes, negative and positive balances are reported separately in aggregate (an overdraft flag is added and for example if the balance changes from 2000 to -1000, -2000 is reported to positive balances and -1000 to overdrafts).

The structure of the table is the following:

| DATE | ACCOUNT | ACCOUNT NAME | BALANCE | CURRENCY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-02 | 1111111 | Account A EUR | 1234.55 | EUR |
| 2020-01-02 | 1123333 | Account B USD | 111.5656 | USD |
| 2020-01-02 | 1111111 | Account A USD | 10.2 | USD |
| 2020-01-03 | 1111111 | Account A EUR | 2222.55 | EUR |
| 2020-01-03 | 1123333 | Account B USD | 111.5656 | USD |
| 2020-01-04 | 1111111 | Account A EUR | 3333.2 | EUR |
| 2020-01-04 | 1111111 | Account A USD | -15 | USD |

I tried to use lead/lag but here I'm facing the problem of accounts that have 0 balance on one of the days so they are missing from the view.

```
[BALANCE] - ISNULL(lag([BALANCE]) OVER (partition BY [ACCOUNT], [CURRENCY], [OVDFlag]
ORDER BY DATE), 0)
```

I do not want to load all account balances including 0 (it would be tens of thousands of extra rows each day).
It is possible to search for account that have balances one day and do not have an entry the next day, however the overdraft flag makes things complicated (it is not part of the original table).

The only way I managed to make the view work is using full outer join using lagged dates as a joining condition. It is not an effective way and the performance will deteriorate quickly with a growing data set.

```
SELECT ...
FROM TABLE1 t1
FULL OUTER JOIN TABLE2 t2 
ON t1.DATE=t2.NextDate AND t1.Account=t2.Account AND t1.Currency=t2.Currency AND t1.OVDFlag=t2.OVDFlag
```

I'm sure there has to be an easy and way more effective way to deal with this but I'm a beginner at this (as you can probably see from the above) and I could really use some help.

Thank you!

Comment: Your goal is logically impossible without knowing when a balance falls to zero. In fact, it is impossible IMO without having all daily balances unless you want to impute all missing balance values (based on whatever logic / formula you desire) and marking them as such in your resultset. If an account is missing a row for date X, you cannot know if that is because the balance fell to zero or if the row was simply not loaded (or worse - accidentally deleted).

Comment: Use a calendar table, left join the other (grouped up) tables to it

Comment: The data is checked for errors and it can be assumed no data is missing and that rows that are not in the table are zero at that particular point in time - does this change the situation? All missing values are imputed to be 0.